# changing log4j file name programatically in osgi maven bundle not working

Tags: java, maven, log4j, apache-karaf

Im developing a maven-osgi bundle and deploying in karaf.. In that, a piece of code, should get .cfg files from the karaf/etc and im programatically changing them at runtime.. writeTrace()  is invoked within 'for loop' from another class. So that I can create different files and corresponding logging should go in to that file.

```
   public void writeLog(int i,String HostName) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("\n  HEADER : \n");
    ....
    String str = sb.toString();
    String logfile = ("/home/Dev/" + HostName + i);
    logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("TracerLog");
    updateLog4jConfiguration(logfile);
    logger.error(str + i);}


    public void updateLog4jConfiguration(String logFile) {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    try {
        // InputStream configStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(
        // "/home/Temp-files/NumberGenerator/src/main/java/log4j.properties");
        InputStream configStream = new FileInputStream("etc/org.ops4j.pax.logging.cfg");
        props.load(configStream);       
        System.out.println(configStream);
        configStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error: Cannot laod configuration file ");
    }
    props.setProperty("log4j.appender.Tracer.File", logFile);
    LogManager.resetConfiguration();
    PropertyConfigurator.configure(props);
}
```

and I am able to see new files created with hostname such as (hostname_1 , hostname_2, etc..) but logging happens only at actual appender configured at karaf/etc... thaat is log.txt..

```
    log4j.logger.TracerLog=TRACE,Tracer
    log4j.appender.Tracer=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
    log4j.appender.Tracer.MaxBackupIndex=10
    log4j.appender.Tracer.MaxFileSize=500KB 
    log4j.appender.Tracer.File=/home/Dev/log.txt
```

I got struck in this error.. Dont know whether it has to do something with the karaf or problem with code..???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why aren't you just using the ConfigurationAdminService for this, instead of altering the file?
Just reference the configuration admin service from the registry and take the configuration with the PID *org.ops4j.pax.logging*.
With this approach you will have all configuration properties available for your proposal and it is in your code to alter this. It's also possible for you to add new configuration entries. In the end the combination of ConfigurationAdminService and the felix FileInstaller will even persist your changes back to the configuration file.

Btw. did you know that there is a shell command for configuring configurations, so actually also to alter the configuration for the org.ops4j.pax.logging service? 
Just do a:

```
config:list
```

to retrieve all configurations available
and a

```
config:list "(service=org.ops4j.pax.logging)"
```

to retrieve just this information.

Comment: since im a newbie to karaf ,Can you quote any code examples for configuratoinAdminService with File Installer..

Comment: That's the part I'm using with Pax Web for testing, with newer versions of Pax Exam this can be done easier, though it's good enough for beeing an example:      https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.web/blob/master/pax-web-itest/pax-web-itest-container/pax-web-itest-container-jetty/src/test/java/org/ops4j/pax/web/itest/jetty/HttpServiceWithConfigAdminIntegrationTest.java#L48

Comment: I saw your code, but im not able to get the configuration file property. `org.osgi.service.cm.Configuration config = caService.getConfiguration("org.ops4j.pax.logging")` I'm not able to get any config properties.. I need you help.

Comment: You need to make sure your test actually does have a configuration Adminservice injected: @Inject
 private ConfigurationAdmin caService;    
And do you have the Felix implementation of it installed?
mavenBundle("org.apache.felix", "org.apache.felix.configadmin", "1.4.0")

Comment: Is there a way to do it in osgi maven bundle(ConfigAdminService) development.. For your clarification Im not doing PAX exam testing.

Comment: I don't know what kind of osgi maven bundle you are talking of, but if you run inside Karaf you just need to retrieve the according ConfigAdminService from the service registry.